# Why isn't my ionic app binding the elements?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

http://codepen.io/BltzLcht/pen/grBGBB

```
<h5>Set timer:</h5></span> <input  class="time" type="number" ng-model="countdown" placeholder="In Mississippis" ng-change="selectTimer()"/>
```

I thought that putting {{countdown}} in would work but it doesn't.
Not sure how to bind the task name with the popup either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ionic js file doesn't exist on codepen you need to link it from cdn, for instance:

```
<script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

### Edit:

### The task name problem:

In your html view you use ionic directives which change the scope, so your ng-model input saves to the new scope. The easiest way to do that will be:

```
$scope.countDown = 0; // number of seconds remaining
$scope.taskData = {}; // <-- add this line to declare object
```

In html change:

```
<input class="row-center" type="text" ng-model="taskData.Task" placeholder="Task to be done" />
```

ng-model Task is inside declared taskData object

and in ionicPopup:

```
title: 'Your ' + $scope.taskData.Task + ' Is Up!',
```

### Setting task time

You should do something similiar (but add new variable, for instance `$scope.taskData.countdownTime` which will be used only to set the time, no to countdown)

Change in html:

```
<input  class="time" type="number" ng-model="taskData.countdownTime" placeholder="In Mississippis" ng-change="selectTimer()"/>
```

Then in JS instead of setting 10 in line:

```
$scope.countDown = 10;
```

set the number of seconds provided by user:

```
$scope.countDown = $scope.taskData.countdownTime;
```

Comment: Thanks! so I have've got to use an array of strings for the text huh

Comment: How come it isn't working the same for the countDown

Comment: I edited it a while ago again with the task time. As I see - now you have it almost done, but you set 5 seconds always instead of time from the input. You can delete the line with setting 5 seconds, but you'll have also your input field changing (time decreasing) or set a new variable as in my answer.

Comment: Ahh I see what you did there, So the taskData.CountdownTime is like an array of sorts?

Comment: It's just the variable - when the user types number (for instance 10) in field called "In Mississippis", that number will be stored in  taskData.CountdownTime. And when you start timer this value is copied to countdown variable (which is used to count down remaining seconds).